# Control UI of one Android app from another

Tags: android, root, sandbox, kiosk-mode

I have one app that runs as a service and broadcast receiver with root and device administrator access. I need that app to be able to control the UI for any other app that may be running. For example, I might want to hide the system nav bar or override the home button while other apps are running in the foreground. It is to sandbox the user.

Can anyone suggest how I might do such a thing? Hiding the nav bar in your own app is easy, and of course overriding buttons is no big deal, but I need for one app to be able to do it for other apps.

I'm considering if the UI Automator could help.

My apps (the sandboxer and the other apps that will be running) are mine and they will all have root access. I will also be able to build my own custom version of the Android OS on each device if I need to.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this needs to be done in a two step process,

1. Create a broadcast from your service
2. Register a broadcast receiver in your UI application to listen to the broadcasts

In your service do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(Intent);
```

In your mainActivity, use

```
registerReceiver(<receiver instance>, BROADCAST_ACTION)
```

in the onStart or onCreate method.

This will setup your mainActivity to listen to the broadcasts, next you need to define your broadcast receiver which is the  in the above register call.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        //Modify the UI, in this case hide the dialog box.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I take this method then all the UI hiding / sandboxing code would be in the main app, and therefore it would have to be in every app that needs to be sandboxed, which would be duplication of code. I want the service to modify the UI, since the same service would ideally be running on all devices no matter which app we choose to run on it for the user to use.

Comment: apologies, i missed the word "any" in the question! I need to think about this